UnsupportedOperationException with flyway migrate
Flyway Community Edition 10.19.0
DEBUG: Java Version: 17.0.11+9
Environment variables set:
FLYWAY_BASELINE_ON_MIGRATE='true'
FLYWAY_CLEAN_DISABLED='true'
FLYWAY_COMMUNITY_DB_SUPPORT_DISABLED='false'
FLYWAY_COMMUNITY_DB_SUPPORT_ENABLED='true'
FLYWAY_LOCATIONS='filesystem:database/migrations'
FLYWAY_OUT_OF_ORDER='true'
FLYWAY_PASSWORD='<password>
FLYWAY_OUT_OF_ORDER='true'
FLYWAY_URL='<jdbc-url>
FLYWAY_USER='myuser'

Ran command
bin/flyway-10.19.0/flyway -flyway.communityDBSupportEnabled=true migrate

Got
ERROR: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
+ bin/flyway-10.19.0/flyway -X -flyway.communityDBSupportEnabled migrate
ERROR: Unexpected error
org.flywaydb.core.api.FlywayException: Invalid flag: -flyway.communityDBSupportEnabled
    at org.flywaydb.commandline.configuration.CommandLineArguments.lambda$validate$19(CommandLineArguments.java:988)
    at java.base/java.util.OptionalInt.ifPresent(Unknown Source)
    at org.flywaydb.commandline.configuration.CommandLineArguments.validate(CommandLineArguments.java:983)
    at org.flywaydb.commandline.Main.main(Main.java:870)

I set both FLYWAY_COMMUNITY_DB_SUPPORT_ENABLED and FLYWAY_COMMUNITY_DB_SUPPORT_DISABLED because the documentation used the positive form (enabled), but the environment variable used the negative form. If I omitted the -flyway.communityDBSupportEnabled=true, it complained about missing an argument.
Is migrate supported with the community edition? What part of my request is not supported?

I believe there is some mismatch with env variable FLYWAY_COMMUNITY_DB_SUPPORT_DISABLED
// org.flywaydb.core.internal.configuration.ConfigUtils
if ("FLYWAY_COMMUNITY_DB_SUPPORT_DISABLED".equals(key)) {
    return COMMUNITY_DB_SUPPORT_ENABLED;
}

Try to use -communityDBSupportEnabled parameter instead of -flyway.communityDBSupportEnabled.
From Community DB Support Enabled:
### Commandline
./flyway -communityDBSupportEnabled="false" migrate

### Configuration File
flyway.communityDBSupportEnabled=false

### Environment Variable
FLYWAY_COMMUNITY_DB_SUPPORT_DISABLED=false

